# How do populate an EditText from one array list based on another array list

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I started making a simple oil changing app but I've hit a wall with it.  I'm not sure if it a fault in my logic or code. You add a car to the app with it's details these go into an array list and the car is displayed on a card view on the main screen showing the name, make, model, etc. When you click on a car from the main screen it opens another screen populated with the car and details with a list of existing oil changes and a button to add new oil change. When an oil change is added it creates another list containing details on the oil change including the name of the car. I have it so whichever car you pick from the main screen shows its own oil change history.  The problem I can't figure out is, I preform a simple calculation to show when the next oil change is due based on miles I would like this value to be displayed on the main screen car card. I can pass a value to the card but the same value keeps going to every car I have listed. I can't figure out how to tie the mileage due value to the correct car.

adding a car

```
 EditText addName;
 EditText addMake;  //from add_car.xml
 EditText addModel, addMiles, addOilType, addOilQuarts, addOilFilter, addAirFilter, addPreferredChange;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_car);

     addName =  findViewById (R.id.txtAddName);
     addMake =  findViewById (R.id.txtAddMake);  //gets whats in txtAddMake from add_car.xml
     addModel = findViewById(R.id.txtAddModel);
     addMiles = findViewById(R.id.txtAddMiles);
     addOilType = findViewById(R.id.txtOilType);
     addOilQuarts = findViewById(R.id.txtOilQuarts);
     addOilFilter = findViewById(R.id.txtOilFilter);
     addAirFilter = findViewById(R.id.txtAirFilter);
     addPreferredChange = findViewById(R.id.txtPreferredChange);

    Button btnAddCar = findViewById(R.id.btnAddCar);
    btnAddCar.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId())
    {
        case R.id.btnAddCar:

             saveCars();

           break;
    }
}

//calling Cars.java
private void saveCars(){
    Cars cars= new Cars(addName.getText().toString(), addMake.getText().toString(),   //System.currentTimeMillis() is time of phone, using as name of file
            addModel.getText().toString(), addMiles.getText().toString(),addOilType.getText().toString(),
            addOilQuarts.getText().toString(),addOilFilter.getText().toString(),addAirFilter.getText().toString(),addPreferredChange.getText().toString());
   if( Utilities.saveCars(this,cars)){    //runs savesCars from utilises class
       Toast.makeText(this, "Car is saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       finish(); //finish go back to previous actity
   }else{
       Toast.makeText(this, "error, check storage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }

}
```

adding oil change

```
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_oil_change);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    addCurMiles = findViewById(R.id.addOilCurrentMiles);
    addCurDate = findViewById(R.id.addOilCurrentDate);
    addDueMiles = findViewById(R.id.addOilDueMiles);
    addDueDate = findViewById(R.id.addOilDueDate);
    addCarName = findViewById(R.id.txtCarName);  //passing the filename 
    btnAddOilChange = findViewById(R.id.btnAddOilChange);
    btnAddOilChange.setOnClickListener(this);

    btnNxtOilChange = findViewById(R.id.btnNxtOilChange);
    btnNxtOilChange.setOnClickListener(this);

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    addCurDate.setText(dateFormat.format(new Date()));

    Intent i = getIntent();
    carFileName = i.getExtras().getString("Car Name");
    addCarName.setText(carFileName);


}


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.btnAddOilChange:
            saveOilChange();
            break;

        case R.id.btnNxtOilChange:
            nextOilChange ();
            break;
    }
}

public void nextOilChange(){
   if(addCurMiles.getText().toString() != null) {
       int num1 = Integer.parseInt(addCurMiles.getText().toString());
       int sum = num1 + 3000;
       addDueMiles.setText(Integer.toString(sum));
       changeOilMiles = addDueMiles.getText().toString();
   }else{

   }
}


 private void saveOilChange(){OilChange oilChange = new 
 OilChange(System.currentTimeMillis(),addCurMiles.getText().toString(), 
 addCurDate.getText().toString(),addDueMiles.getText().toString(), 
 addDueDate.getText().toString(), addCarName.getText().toString());  
 //using System.currentTimeMillis(), for file name using .oil as extension 
    //Write next oil change to main card here!

    if( Utilities.saveOilChange(this,oilChange)){             
        setResult(RESULT_OK);
        finish(); //finish go back to previous activity
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "error, check storage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Where I populate the oil change on cars card but it goes to all cars

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent 
data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(this, "hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    txtOilChangeDue.setText(AddOilChange.changeOilMiles);
}
```

Display car cards and open new activity when car clicked

```
//this populates the list view
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    main_car_list.setAdapter(null);
    cars = Utilities.getAllSavedCars(this);
//for context menu
    registerForContextMenu(main_car_list);

    if(cars == null || cars.size() == 0){
        Toast.makeText(this,"you have no cars added", 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }else{

     ca = new CarAdapter(this, R.layout.car_list, cars); 
        main_car_list.setAdapter(ca);

//when click item(car) opens new activity
        main_car_list.setOnItemClickListener(new 
  AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, 
  int position, long l) { //tabbed automatically filled in this
                String fileName = 
((Cars)main_car_list.getItemAtPosition(position)).getName() + 
 Utilities.FILE_EXTENSION; //gets filename
                Intent viewCar = new 
 Intent(getApplicationContext(),CarDetails.class); //when clicked on item 
 in list opens deails
                //this is how pass data between activities
              //   this passes car name and model to CarDetails
                viewCar.putExtra("Car_File", fileName);  

                startActivity(viewCar);

            }
        });

        }

    }
```

**Please add your adapter class

Cars adapter class

```
public class CarAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Cars>  {

public CarAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Cars> cars) {
    super(context, resource, cars);
}



@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  //  return super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);

    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.car_list, null); //car_list xml
    }

    Cars cars = getItem(position);
    if(cars != null){
        TextView txtName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        TextView txtMake = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtMake);  //from car_list reads what's there (i think)
        TextView txtModel =convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtModel);
        TextView txtMiles = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtMiles);
        TextView txtOilChangeDue = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtOilChangeDue);
       // TextView txtOilChangeDueMiles = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtOilChangeDueMileage);

        txtName.setText(cars.getName());
        txtMake.setText(cars.getMake());
        txtModel.setText(cars.getModel());
        txtMiles.setText(cars.getMiles());
        txtOilChangeDue.setText(AddOilChange.changeOilMiles);  //replaces value each time and on both/all cars
        //txtOilChangeDue.setText("hi"); works
   //     txtDueMileage.setText(cars.getDueMileage());
       // txtDate.setText(cars.getDateTimeFormatted(getContext())); //not sure what for

    }

    return convertView;
}
}
```

Oil Adapter Class

```
public class OilAdapter extends ArrayAdapter <OilChange> {




public OilAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<OilChange> oilchange) {  //use ctrl+insert to add this change object to oilchange
    super(context, resource, oilchange);                            //had list changed to ArrayList (didnt seem to make a difference)
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  //use ctrl+o to add overide choose getView
 //   return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);  //not sure why i have to comment out

    if (convertView == null){
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.oil_change_records,null);  //layout should (in this case) be card view list
    }                                                                                                       //this just calls list below will populate it

    OilChange oc = getItem(position); //oc - any name u want , position - gets items out of list(i think)
    if(oc != null){
        TextView cDate = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtOilRecDate);  //gets text views from oil change records list
        TextView cMiles = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtOilRecMiles);

        cDate.setText(oc.getCurDate());  //this sets the current date and miles from info just added for the oil change
        cMiles.setText(oc.getDueMiles());
    }
    //getting last record
    if(position==getCount()-1)
    {

    }

  return convertView;
  }


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been in this before and from your code above, in the CarAdapter you provided a constant `AddOilChange.changeOilMiles` that why the values are the same

**txtOilChangeDue.setText(*AddOilChange.changeOilMiles*);**

Solution:

1) Create an extra field in the `Car` model

```
private String changeOil;
........
//create setter and getter for changeOil
```

then obtain the current car to be updated and update the changeOil of the car while saving the oilChange in **adding oil change**

2) Pass the OilChange array list to the CarAdapter

```
ArrayList<OilChange> oliChanges;

public CarAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Cars> cars, ArrayList<OilChange> oilChanges) {
    super(context, resource, cars);
     this.oilChanges = oilChanges;
}

..........

 Cars cars = getItem(position);
 OilChange oilChange = oilChanges.get(position);
    if(cars != null){
        TextView txtName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        TextView txtMake = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtMake);  //from car_list reads what's there (i think)
        TextView txtModel =convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtModel);
        TextView txtMiles = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtMiles);
        TextView txtOilChangeDue = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtOilChangeDue);
       // TextView txtOilChangeDueMiles = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtOilChangeDueMileage);

        txtName.setText(cars.getName());
        txtMake.setText(cars.getMake());
        txtModel.setText(cars.getModel());
        txtMiles.setText(cars.getMiles());

//obtain the oilchange from the model ensure you have created a getOilChange() method in OilChange class to obtain the oilchange
        txtOilChangeDue.setText(oilChange.getOilChange());  //replaces value each time and on both/all cars
```

Comment: sorry haven't much time to work on it...thank you for your response. i did get the new code in but i'm getting errors. i will trouble shoot them tomorrow and let you know how it goes. i'm getting and error on this line    OilChange oilChange = oilChange.getItem(position); saying variable might not have been initialized and hreetxtOilChangeDue.setText(oilChange.getOilChange());  saying cannot resolve method "getOilChange"  thanks

Comment: Ensure you are sending an initialized OilChange model to the adapter and also oilChange.getOilChange() should be be a method in your OilChange model to get the value.

Comment: should this be OilChange oilChange = oilChange.get(position); orOilChange oilChange = oilChanges.get(position);  thanks

Comment: Edited it should be oilChanges.getOilChange(position) ;

Comment: that's what i changed it to ...but wasn't sure it was correct and wanted to ask. getting closer. Crashing right now...but haven't debugged it yet.

Comment: i must not be initializing my adapter i continue to get a null error reference you said "Ensure you are sending an initialized OilChange model to the adapter"  i've added this but it's not correct. sorry i'm way out of my league here.                    
        Cars cars = getItem(position);
        ArrayList<OilChange> oilChanges = null;  //initializing empty
        OilChange oilChange = oilChanges.get(position);

Comment: sorry, i'm really trying to figure this out. but i'm getting a null object reference now, from this line  ca = new CarAdapter(this, R.layout.car_list, cars, oilChanges); and i'm not sure what to do. thanks

Comment: This should be from your `oilChanges` You might have not initialized `oilChanges` in the before `ca = new CarAdapter(this, R.layout.car_list, cars, oilChanges);` was called. Kindly post the full activity code, you posted the onResume method only above

Comment: thanks i edited the above and posted the full MainActivity.  thanks